# Frama-c fails to prove verify.c from Allan Blanchard's tutorial

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to learn frama-c from Allan Blanchard's [tutorial](https://allan-blanchard.fr/category/teaching.html) and I have had trouble verifying the installation as suggested in the tutorial. The author provides a [C file](https://github.com/AllanBlanchard/tutoriel_wp/blob/master/code/program-proof-and-our-tool/frama-c/verify.c) with ACSL annotations, all of which frama-c is supposed to be able to prove. However when I run the command (`frama-c-gui -wp -rte main.c`) I get the following:

[Frama-C GUI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08ejv.png)

I installed frama-c (version 22.0) via opam (version 2.0.4) on an ocaml-base-compiler.4.11.1 switch. When I installed it I had an issue with Why3 not being able to detect Alt-Ergo and I ended up editing ~/why3.config manually. I mention it here even though I am not sure whether or not it's related to the aformentioned problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can judge based on the screenshot, this seems pretty much related indeed. Notably, whenever you see `Failed` after a prover, this is a sign that something went wrong: a prover simply unable to prove something would rather be indicated as `Unknown`.

In your case, I'd tend to think that the issue comes from the fact that Alt-Ergo 2.4.0, the version you are using, is fairly recent (more recent than the latest Why3 version in fact), and is not yet supported by Why3. As mentioned in the [reference configuration](https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/-/blob/master/reference-configuration.md) for Frama-C, Alt-Ergo 2.2.0 is known to be fully supported, hence you may want to `opam pin add alt-ergo 2.2.0` to work with that version. After that, don't forget to have Why3 re-detect the provers `why3 config --detect-provers`. Should this step be a problem, feel free to open a new question on this specific topic (though I suspect that the issue was related to Alt-Ergo 2.4.0).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it worked like a charm!